# Save Postgres query in PHP variable

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have the following Postgres query:

```
$sql_afect = "SELECT SUM(r.num_tiempo_afectado) FROM ctl_reportes r 
    WHERE 1 = 1 AND r.num_tiempo_afectado <> '00:00:00' " . (!empty($idu_clase) ? 
    "AND r.idu_clase = $idu_clase" : "") . " " . (!empty($idu_prioridad) ? 
    "AND r.idu_prioridad = $idu_prioridad" : "");
```

I'm working on a PHP program, and this query **sums** a bunch of some specific hours, which are in this format on a table (ctl_reportes): '**00:00:00**'.

How could I save this query's result into a PHP variable in order to **echo** the result on the screen?

Comment: How to save the result or the query? Do you execute the query?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php - http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php - http://razorsql.com/articles/postgresql_column_names_values.html

Comment: just do what you normally would do, execute query then fetch

Answer (score 0):

See the code below to execute query in PHP using `PDO`

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = 'toor';
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_scrapper', $user, $pass);

$query = "SELECT SUM(r.num_tiempo_afectado) FROM ctl_reportes r 
    WHERE 1 = 1 AND r.num_tiempo_afectado <> '00:00:00' " . (!empty($idu_clase) ? 
    "AND r.idu_clase = $idu_clase" : "") . " " . (!empty($idu_prioridad) ? 
    "AND r.idu_prioridad = $idu_prioridad" : "");

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();

/* Exercise PDOStatement::fetch styles */
print("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: ");
print("Return next row as an array indexed by column name\n");

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```

Here after query is executed, the result is stored in `$result`. I assume you have some
basic knowledge to use PHP. Please refer to [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to have more insights into it.

Please let us know if this works for you or not. And I'll update my answer accordingly.